# Android CustomListAdapter with parent and child

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

did the ExpandableListAdapter is the correct way for make this

i want to make chat app and i have problem here

lets see this two image and i will explain

first image make message with baseAdapter i mean CustomListAdapter and message as List array with ListView

so my List array to CustomBaseAdapter  will be something  like

[message 1,message 2, message 3 ]

[image]

now if i want do some thing like this i cant do it with base adapter
because every message have some Child

so my List array to CustomBaseAdapter  will be something  like

[message 1 : [hi,some other message , image , message ] ,message 2 : [ok ,hello world , nice ,image]]

every message as parts of message i cant do it with CustomBaseAdapter its need some thing like BaseExpandableListAdapter  but problem with BaseExpandableListAdapter i dont know if i can style it like message in second photo

[image]

we can see every message its a parts of messages i search and i just found

> BaseExpandableListAdapter

can solve my problem but i cant style it like this messages any idea how to make 
CustomListAdapter inside CustomListAdapter or how can i do some thing like second image every message as parts of message

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: @Pravin its help little but not resolve the problem .. i want all the image and message put them as another CustomAdapter for user image its be like this .. Pravin send message his message contain images and multi line off message now for every line and image i need make CustomListAdapter  lets named as myAdapter now this adapter contain only messages withou photo of who send this message i dont want to add 
photo for who send this message for every line off message

Comment: its possible just create separate POGO classes